# History maintaining in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User Model which has many fields including weight of the user. Admin user can change the weight of a particular user at any time. Is it possible to maintain weight history of a particular user.

Comment: Is the weight the only attribute you foresee changing or do you need a more generic way to record attribute changes?

Comment: currently i need to maintain only weight attribute history.....is it possible in rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to do model versioning but there are a bunch of gems that could help you. I suggest looking at [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) and [vestal_versions](https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions).

Ryan Bates has some good screencasts covering some of the functionality:

- [Undo with Paper Trail](http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail)
- [Model Versioning](http://railscasts.com/episodes/177-model-versioning)

I'd suggest focusing on paper_trail as it's still being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.  Not without whipping up some code or using a gem.  I'd suggest you take a look through some of these... Papertrail in particular seems to be very popular.

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning

Comment: another option is https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions although I agree that paper trail is more popular